# I want to Translate multiple languages in textarea. Translated successfully. but in textarea it shows all the code with translated data

Tags: ajaxform

I want to Translate multiple languages in textarea. Translated successfully. but in textarea it shows all the code with translated data.
It will return actual data in textarea.
Please find the Error
this response error

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#trans_lang").on('click', function () {

            let inputtext = $("textarea[name='prayer_points']").val();
            let sourceLang = $(".source-lang").val();
            let targetLang = $(".target-lang").val();
            let prayerId = $("input[name='id']").val();

            let postData = {
                'text': inputtext,
                'source_lang': sourceLang,
                'target_lang': targetLang,
                'id': prayerId
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: 'editprayerpoint.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: postData,
                success: function (res) {
                    console.log("Translation Response:", res);
                    $(".output").val(res);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.error("AJAX Error:", textStatus, errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });


    </script>
```

Comment: By code, do you mean HTML tags are being put into the textarea? What does editprayerpoint.php render?